# WPF Longtouch interferes with TouchEnter

Tags: wpf, xaml, touch

I have a rectangle which should trigger an event on TouchEnter.
But when I Touch the rectangle nothing happens until the longtouch is over. It looks like it is waiting to be sure there is no longtouch before the TouchEnter kicks in.

If I touch the rectangle and move slightly (so there can't be a LongTouch anymore) it triggers the event.

How can I get rid of this:
"I better wait for the longTouch to be finished until I trigger the touchEnter" ?

The same happens with the TouchDown event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set as high as possible in the visual tree the attached properties [Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.ispressandholdenabled.aspx) and [Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.isflicksenabled.aspx) to false in xaml or in code.

These will disable most of the delay experienced when doing a touch enter and down due to the touch needing the delay to figure out what the user wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

It happened only on my Touch-Monitor.
Using a Tablet it worked fine.

So I think it depends on the Hardware.